# Using delegation to talk to view controllers in TabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, delegates, protocols

I'm trying to use protocols and delegation to send messages to different views in a tab bar controller. I've set it up like below but I don't seem to be receiving the message;

```
@class RaprTabBarViewController;

@protocol RaprTabBarViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)initActivites:(NSArray *)activities;

@end


@interface RaprTabBarViewController : UITabBarController <RKObjectLoaderDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <RaprTabBarViewControllerDelegate> delegated;

@end
```

Then in the implementation

```
- (void)someMethodThatIsCalled:(NSArray *)objects {
    NSLog(@"Delegating..");
    [self.delegated initActivites:objects];
}
```

Now I get the NSLog so the method is definitely called. And now here is a view controller which is embedded in a navigation controller;

```
@interface ActivitesViewController : UITableViewController <RaprTabBarViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *activites;

@end
```

And the implementation

```
- (void)initActivites:(NSArray *)activities {
    NSLog(@"Called initActivities");
    self.activites = activities;
}
```

I do not get the NSLog in the view controller so the initActivites method is never called. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In `someMethodThatIsCalled`, has `delegated` been initialized before you send it `initActivites:objects`?

Comment: Actually no it hasn't, how would I initialise it without knowing what object it's going to be? Appreciate the help

Comment: Your answer to j.tom.schroeder is confusing. You must be tying the delegate to something?

Comment: `delegated` needs to be assigned before calling `someMethodThatIsCalled`. I recommend you review your design and verify you have everything planned out before coding it up. Is it best for a TabBarController to initialize the activities of the TableView? This seems convoluted. A simple design is rarely a bad thing.

Comment: What I was trying to do is assign data to the tableView as the TabBarController does all the data fetching. I wanted to do this without saying `[[self.viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]` as I find this a bit messy. I must admit my biggest downfall is understanding the best way for different classes to talk to each other. How would you recommend I send the data to the tableview?

Comment: Ok I have got the delegation working now by initialising the `delegated` property from the actual TableViewController, now I understand how that works. But you say this is a convoluted way of doing things, you think it's better just to assign using the `self.viewControllers` way?